# Display error if one radio button is unchecked?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm sorry if I'm asking in mysql_* format, as it is what I'm using right now. I still hope you guys could help me.

So my problem is, I'm trying to display an error once a form is submitted wherein one row of radio buttons is unchecked. However, based on my code, it only appears on the specific row and not as a single message on top because I think I have included it inside a While-Loop. Can you guys advice a way on how to do it? Be it a javascript or function, I'm fine with it. I just don't know how to do it :P.

Here's my code:

```
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

//DISPLAY ALL ANSWERS
if(isset($_POST['voted'])){
    if(in_array($_POST['score('.$fetch['questionID'].')'], $radioValue)){
        echo "<tr>Question no. ",$fetch['questionID'],": ",
        $_POST['score('.$fetch['questionID'].')'],"<br></tr>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<center><font color=red>All fields are required</font><br><br>
        <input type='button' name='return' value='Return' onclick='history.go(-1)'><br>";
        exit();
    }
}

//DISPLAYS QUESTIONS WITH QUESTION NUMBER
echo "<tr align=left><th><font face='Courier New,arial' size=2px>".$fetch["questionID"].". ".$fetch["question"]."<br>
    <td><font face='Courier New,arial' size=2px>";


//DISPLAYS RADIO BUTTONS FROM 1 to 5    
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
    echo "<input type=radio name='score(".$fetch["questionID"].")' value=",$i," >"; echo $i;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a variable inside the while loop to check for errors.  Something like the following:

```
$validationFailed = false;
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

//DISPLAY ALL ANSWERS
if(isset($_POST['voted'])){
if(in_array($_POST['score('.$fetch['questionID'].')'], $radioValue)){
    echo "<tr>Question no. ",$fetch['questionID'],": ",
    $_POST['score('.$fetch['questionID'].')'],"<br></tr>";
}
else{
    $validationFailed = true;
    exit();
}
}

//following should be outside the while loop.
if($validationFailed) {
    echo "<center><font color=red>All fields are required</font><br><br>
    <input type='button' name='return' value='Return' onclick='history.go(-1)'><br>";
}
```

Comment: Is it really that simple??? Man what have I been thinking... Thanks. I'll try that and respond what happens.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected... But thanks anyway, I've gotten an idea wherein I just placed an error checker which increments on every missing radio button.

Answer (score 0):

first of all please use same name for radio button and value will be differ.
and now try this code on submit if true then post your form else display error message

```
var iz_checked = true;
$('input').each(function(){
   iz_checked = iz_checked && $(this).is(':checked');
});
```

Comment: I actually have same names. But unfortunately, I tied it with a while loop since I'm just fetching my questions from a DB and printing each in every while iteration.

Comment: Thanks. But I've found a simpler way wherein I just used an incrementing variable to check missing fields.